# how to obtain 2d Gaussian kernel in matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, gaussian

How do I obtain 2D circularly symmetric
Gaussian weighting function sampled out to 3
standard deviations (3 x 3) and re scaled to unit volume?

Comment: What's wrong with [randn](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`fspecial`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) (Image Processing Toolbox) with the `'gaussian'` option. For example,

```
z = fspecial('gaussian', [30 30], 4);
```

generates values on a `30`×`30` grid with sampling step `1` and standard deviation `4`.

```
surf(z)
```

produces the graph

[image]

The function is normalized to unit volume. To check this, note that the sampling step is `1`, so that the Riemann sum approximating the integral is just the sum of all function values:

```
>> sum(z(:))
ans =
    1.0000
```