# Why do mvnpdf and fspecial('gaussian') give different matrices in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I'm trying to generate a 2D Gaussian kernel in MatLab. I found two ways to do it.
1. Using [mvnpdf](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html)

```
mu = [0 0];
sigma = 1.4;
sigma_mat = 1/sigma^2 * eye(2);
x1 = -3:1:3;
x2 = x1;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
G = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,sigma_mat);
F = reshape(G,length(x2),length(x1));
```

This gives the below matrix

```
0    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0.01 0    0    0
0    0    0.04 0.12 0.04 0    0
0    0.01 0.12 0.31 0.12 0.01 0
0    0    0.04 0.12 0.04 0    0
0    0    0    0.01 0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

2. Using [fspecial('gaussian')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412586/3337089)

`f = fspecial('gaussian', [7,7], 1.4);`

This gives the matrix as

```
0.00    0.00    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.01    0.02    0.03    0.02    0.01    0.00
0.01    0.02    0.05    0.06    0.05    0.02    0.01
0.01    0.03    0.06    0.08    0.06    0.03    0.01
0.01    0.02    0.05    0.06    0.05    0.02    0.01
0.00    0.01    0.02    0.03    0.02    0.01    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.00    0.00
```

What is the difference between these 2 functions? Why are they giving different outputs?
Thanks!

**Edit 1:** As [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) rightly pointed out, there was an error in `sigma_mat`. It should be

```
sigma_mat = sigma^2 * eye(2);
```

Even after that, there are some minor differences in decimal points.

Comment: Oh! You're right. It should be `sigma_mat = sigma^2 * eye(2);` sigma_mat has to be covariance matrix. I missed noting that mvnpdf takes inverse of sigma_mat. Even after that, there are some minor differences in decimal points. Any idea why? I'll update the question in a while

Comment: Perfect. Please post these both comments as answer. I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGMA` input parameter to `mvnpdf` should be

```
sigma_mat = sigma^2 * eye(2);
```

Even with the same sigmas, the two matrices generated are not the same. `fspecial` ensures that `sum(f(:))==1`. Since you're cutting off the tails, this normalization is slightly different from that of the PDF of a normal distribution. You'll notice larger differences when reducing `sigma` (because of increased loss of information with sampling) and when reducing the size of the output matrix (because this cuts off more of the tails). For large `sigma` and large output matrix size the differences should be very small.

The reason `fspecial` normalizes this way is because the output is meant as a convolution kernel. When applying a smoothing filer, the filter weights should sum up to 1 to avoid the average image intensity changing. If you intend to use the generated kernel for image processing, use `fspecial` or normalize the output of `mvnpdf`.